# TextView and Logcat encoding

Tags: java, android, encoding, textview, logcat

I have a server that uses "windows-1254" encoding. My client reading the data over a socket and creates a textview and adds to the screen. I have an issue with the encoding.

Here is my client:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress servAddress = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
        socked = new Socket(servAddress, SERVERPORT);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socked.getInputStream(), "windows-1254"));
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            String read = input.readLine();
            Log.v("Information",read);
            //                  Log.v("Information","msg: " + read);
            updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and my update thread:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    TextView tv = new TextView(cont);
    tv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    Log.v("Information", msg);
    tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tv.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    //          tv.setText(msg);
    tv.setText(makeTextWithColors(msg));
    screen.addView(tv);
}
```

The method makeTextWithColors do some parsing and add  tags to colour the texts according to the ANSI escapes from the server which is not changing any encoding of the text.

The problem here is that when i use the Log.v("Information", "msg: " + read); instead of the original one, i get extra newlines. But when i post the original text to the log cat, somehow log cat removes those newline characters which is actually what i want. Is there a special newline character that i can avoid in windows-1254 encoding that I'm not aware of?

For people who want to check the output of the server, 
Server IP: www.turkmud.com
Port: 4000

In the output, there is a text based picture as you can see, and the newlines corrupts them.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like server was sending \n and \r in a row every time it sends a post. I used a control to see if there was a newline character to avoid them.